# Traer valor por defecto en campo de formulario laravel

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, json

Buena tarde para todos... tengo un formulario donde quisiera que uno de los campos se llenara automáticamente al cargar mi vista con el valor predeterminado de la empresa logueada actualmente. es decir, mi campo es empresa, y si el usuario con el que estoy ingresando pertenece a la empresa GOOGLE, que este sea el valor que me traiga al cargar siempre el formulario.

mis tablas son las siguientes:

> EMPRESA(id,nombre,nit)
>
> USUARIO(id, nombre, empresa_id)
>
> ORDENES(id, paciente,empresa_id)

En mi formulario tengo lo siguiente

```
                  <div class="form-group label-floating">
                    <label class="control-label"">Empresa</label>
                    <input name="empresa" type="text" class="form-control1">
                  </div>
```

agradezco de antemano su valiosa ayuda.

Comment: Si tiene bien definida sus relaciones en sus modelos, puede hacer `<input name="empresa" type="text" class="form-control1" value="{{ auth()->user()->empresa->nombre}}">`

Comment: puedes poner como defines tus relaciones ?

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacerlo de una manera facil debes primero relacionar tus tablas en el modelo, quedaria de la siguiente forma y debería ser en el modelo del Usuario de la siguiente manera:

```html
public function empresa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Empresa::class);
    }
```

Y luego desde la vista que requieras llamar el nombre de la empresa lo podrias realizar de la siguiente manera:

```html
<div class="form-group label-floating">
  <label class="control-label"">Empresa</label>
  <input name="empresa" type="text" class="form-control1" value="{{ auth()->user->empresa->nombre }}">
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @Edjabe , lo resolví de la siguiente manera.

OrdenController

public function create(){
 $empresa= ['' => ''] + Empresa::pluck('nombre','id')->toArray();
 $usuario = Users::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
  return view('ordenes.create', compact('empresa', 'usuario'));
    }

Modelo Users

public function empresaUsuario()
 {
  return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Empresa','id','empresa_id');
 }

Vista Ordenes create.blade

<input name="empresa" type="text" class="form-control1" readonly="true" value="{{ $usuario->empresaUsuario->nombre }}">